# Moving an accelerator Dataset to an other computer

Tags: python

We have been running all our [accelerator](https://www.exax.org) jobs on our shared server. Now, however, we would like to take out a small development subset of our main dataset and work in isolation on our own laptops.

Is it possible to produce a dataset on one machine and move it to an other, hopefully without exporting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no. As long as you use the same number of slices on both computers you can copy the jobdir as is. If the dataset has parents you will need to copy those jobs as as well. Keep the job names, and don't build jobs in that workdir on your laptop (so you can copy newer jobs from the server without ID collisions later).

You don't have to copy previous jobs in the chain as long as you don't try to follow the chain on the laptop.

This is probably the way you want to go, and just have accept having too many slices on your laptop.